# Is there any way to block these popups on websites?

Tags: web, facebook, popups

[image]

These get really annoying if you're just following a link to  watch a news video.

**Edit:** I used Adblock Plus just now to block all the different elements that make up that popup:

```
||facebook.com/plugins/page.php?adapt_container_width=false&app_id=&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FTlA_zCeMkxl.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df39576dfa%26domain%3Dwww.usapoliticstoday.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.usapoliticstoday.com%252Ff3163fac4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=400&height=250&hide_cover=true&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FUSA-Politics-Today-1161632783864856%2F&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&show_facepile=true&show_posts=false&small_header=false&width=400

usapoliticstoday.com##span[style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 400px; height: 214px;"]

usapoliticstoday.com##.fb-page.fb_iframe_widget

usapoliticstoday.com###arvlbdata

usapoliticstoday.com###arevicofancy-content

usapoliticstoday.com###arevicofancy-bg-n
usapoliticstoday.com##.arevicofancy-bg

usapoliticstoday.com###arevicofancy-wrap
```

After doing so I cleared my cookies and reloaded the site and it's "greyed out" and there's no way to close the popup anymore to continue browsing the site. [link](http://www.usapoliticstoday.com/obama-flatly-refuses-french-presidents-invitation-to-join-forces-against-isis-video/)

Comment: Google "pop up blocker"

Comment: I'm using Adblock Plus.

Answer (score 1):

These are javascript enabled modals on the website. If you want to disable them you will need to either block javascript altogether (in which case the page may not longer work), or figure out how they are loading their popups and prevent that code from executing. You could this several ways, including running your own javascript on the page that removes event handlers or if they are loading a specific file for that functionality, prevent it from being loaded. This will most likely only work on one website once you determine how they do it and not work for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you know adblockplus (https://adblockplus.org)?

It blocks many Ads. Also CSS based ones:
https://m.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/1sq3xk/today_i_discovered_that_adblock_blocks_elements/

Comment: Great to know that Ad Block Plus is starting to do that. I use it on all of my desktops so I wouldn't know if I should be seeing them anyways!

Comment: I'm using ad-block but it doesn't automatically block that type. I can manually add it but I think I'd have to do it for every site (I think?). I was hoping to block that type of pop-up completely in one go.